# Can't see PHPMYADMIN Control Panel

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a problem with PHPMYADMIN. I'm trying to create a database on local with my Mac but this is what I see when I'm inside PHPMYADMIN: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtMik.png.

As you can see there is no control panel. It seems like I'm not admin of my PHPMYADMIN or maybe I'm just a guest..

This is the config file of my database:

```
<?php
/*
 * Generated configuration file
 * Generated by: phpMyAdmin 4.4.8 setup script
 * Date: Thu, 04 Jun 2015 15:01:24 +0000
 */

/* Servers configuration */
$i = 1;

/* Server: localhost [1] */
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';

/* End of servers configuration */

$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'it';
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = '–––––––––––.––––––';
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';
$cfg['ServerDefault'] = 1;
?>
```

Comment: What package are you using? `MAMP` or `XAMP`?

Comment: Sorry if it's not what you wanted to know.. I installed this in order to run a mysql database: http://i.imgur.com/O4O4PZp.png

Comment: Try setting a password for your root account

Comment: Nope, I'm logged anyway because of the cookie

Comment: I set a password for my root but it didn't work neither

Comment: Ok I managed to access mysql. I completely remove mysql and phpmyadmin from my system. Reinstalling mysql using "bash <(curl -Ls http://git.io/eUx7rg)" in terminal will generate a password on the desktop that will be the real root password

Comment: Have you tried to use Adminer? It's -to my point of view- a way more better than PHPMyAdmin with less configuration. See it here http://www.adminer.org/

Answer (score 0):

This is what I personally did to solve my problem.

1. Uninstalled and deleted (is important! delete them totally!) mysql and phpmyadmin from the system. You can find mysql in /usr/local on OSX 10.10
2. Typed in the terminal `bash <(curl -Ls http://git.io/eUx7rg)` and then Enter
3. Wait till the end of the download and a simple guided setup will help you re-installing mysql

Now you should have on your Desktop a file named 'MYSQL_PASSWORD' and it will be the password that you will use with phpmyadmin (nickname is root).